# SQL Dependency on SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sqldependency

I have an application which successfully uses SqlDependency with SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition. But if I switch the connection string to SQL Server 2008 express (with enabled Broker) it stops working.

I'm not sure whether it is SQL Server Express specific, but which steps should I follow to find out the reason of the problem?

Update. By "stops working" I mean notifications are not raised by SqlDependency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand how SQL Dependency works, I recommend that you read [The Mysterious Notification](https://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/). To troubleshoot it, follow the normal [Troubleshooting Dialogs](https://rusanu.com/2005/12/20/troubleshooting-dialogs/) steps. The typical culprit is indeed, as in the article you found, the `EXECUTE AS` context required by Service Broker message delivery. You would see this easily from the `transmission_status` of the notification messages in [`sys.transmission_queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-transmission-queue-transact-sql) and changing the database owner to a valid login (`ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<dbname>] TO [sa]`) will fix it. However, there could be other problems. The troubleshooting steps in my link will help you find them.

Answer (score 3):

As @Remus has pointed out, my assumptions based on the misleading documentation were wrong: SQL Server Express does support Service Broker to some extent, despite many online sources stating that it does not support SSB it all. Leaving this up here though so that searches may yield the dialog that ensued.

<strike>It seems that SqlDependency relies on Query Notifications. Query notifications in turn rely on Service Broker. Service Broker is not supported in SQL Server Express. This page doesn't list Query Notifications explicitly:</strike>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(SQL.100).aspx

But from there you can see that Service Broker is supported by Express as a *client* only, and from the following page you can see that Service Broker is a dependency (no pun intended):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: But what does "client only" mean?

Comment: It means that service broker on another instance can *send* messages to Express, but Express can't send messages itself - either within the instance or out to other instances.

Comment: -1 Service Broker is fully supported in Express Editions. The only restriction is that two Express instances cannot exchange messages w/o routing trough a higher edition first. SQL Dependency and query notifications work just fine in SQL Express

Comment: @Remus can you explain then why the SQL Server 2008 doc that I pointed to says that Service Broker is supported as a client only in Express?

Comment: Some other docs are, at best, vague. This one makes it sound like it will only work in conjunction with other editions (implying not as stand-alone): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165704(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I know the docs are often vague and, believe you me, I'm not at all happy with how this particular restriction is described in BOL. I couldn't ever find a single reader that was able to explain what 'supported in client only mode' means. *Everybody* reads it the same way you do, as in 'SSB is disabled in Express'.