# SQL Dependency not Firing

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqldependency

I've tried setting up an SQL Dependency to fire on a "Count Rows" query (written in C#, SQL Server 2008 Express), but after the original subscription SQLNotificationType goes, the event handler never seems to want to fire again (despite rows being added, and I've checked the SQL and it's returning the expected value...).

My code is below.  Any thoughts are much appreciated!

EDIT:  The project that this code is in is a WPF program.  I have this particular code stored in a separate class, which my WPF program creates an instance of in an 'Initialized' event handler.  I then have a method in this class that basically calls ConnectToDatabase() first, and then calls SetupSQLDependency().

EDIT 2:  As a side note, this program is a WPF which I was hoping to distribute to a few users.  The goal was to have the WPF update with certain information whenever new rows were added to a database.  I thought that this would be the best way to go about it, as opposed to always querying the database.

```
        private void ConnectToDatabase()
        {
        //This method is the first to be called, and is the entry 
        // point into my SQL database code.

            databaseConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            // Setup command used in SqlDependecy 
            SqlCommand tempCmd = new SqlCommand();
            tempCmd.Connection = databaseConnection;
            tempCmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM [Example].[dbo].[ExampleTable]";
            sqlCmd = tempCmd;

            try
            { databaseConnection.Open(); }
            catch (Exception e)
            { writeDebug(e.ToString()); }
        }        

        private void SetupSQLDependency()
        {
            SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

            sqlCmd.Notification = null;

            // create new dependency for SqlCommand
            SqlDependency sqlDep = new SqlDependency(sqlCmd);
            sqlDep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(sqlDep_OnChange);

            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        }

        private void sqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            // FROM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/a52dhwx7.aspx

            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
            //++++++ THIS IS THE BLOCK THAT IS NEVER TRIGGERED ++++++//
                // Have to remove this as it only work's once
                SqlDependency sqlDep = sender as SqlDependency;
                sqlDep.OnChange -= sqlDep_OnChange;

                // Resetup Dependecy
                SetupSQLDependency();
            }
            else if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Subscribe)
            {
                double te = 12; // Used this just to test a break... code is useless
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on where this code exists on how it is called?  For example if this code exists in a `Page` and is called in the `OnLoad` event, then you have to remember that your page class is only alive for a split second while the page is being rendered and then a whole new class is instantiated for each request.  So your event subscription, and the `sqlCmd` variable instance are not kept around (and theoeretically are causing mem leaks).

Comment: OK, for some reason I thought you were doing this in ASP.NET.  So does your `SqlNotificationType.Change` fire once and only once, or never at all?

Comment: Ah, yea a plain 'ol WPF.  The only time it fire's is when: e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Subscribe, but never again..

Comment: Is this a static class?  Is it possible the connection and/or the command are being disposed somewhere?

Comment: You've mentioned `SQL Express`, which jumped out at me as I swear it does not support the Broker Service you require for the SQLDependencies, but I am having real trouble finding a definitive statement of such on MSDN.  I'll keep digging, but I'd recommend it as something to investigate.  We have almost identical code to yours running on SQL Server 2008 Developer and Standard editions, we did not try Express because of this somewhat elusive statement regarding the Express edition...

Comment: Here's a similar question which may be of use to you which effectively nullifies my previous comment =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955290/sql-dependency-on-sql-server-2008-express

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the heads up, I'll take a look around.  This class is not in a static class anywhere....  maybe that's doing it, would it get disposed after the initialized event handler finished running through?? (ie WPF form loads, then calls its event handler which sets up this class and connects to the database etc. Then after it sets up the SQL dependency event handler (and instantly calls it via subscribe) then finishes its constructor, and then just gets disposed?)

Comment: Although @Coding Gorilla's comment was based on an ASP.Net setup, he is right that you should consider the scope of the dependency(s).  They are certainly best managed from a persistent application level layer and not tied to a form/class which is likely to go out of scope.  In ASP.Net you would likely use the ApplicationContext or the ASP.Net Cache mechanisms, similar approaches would likely be a good idea in your WPF app too.  An article on using SqlDependencies in WPF can be found here: http://eclipsed4utoo.com/blog/sqldependency-monitor-sql-database/  Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Smudge.  I've seen that tutorial posted elsewhere as well.  Out of curiosity, could it be the using {  }  that makes a difference?  Ive never used those before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem here is the `COUNT`. Refer to the [MSDN documentation for Supported SELECT Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx) for more info:

> The projected columns in the SELECT statement may not contain aggregate expressions unless the statement uses a GROUP BY expression. When a GROUP BY expression is provided, the select list may contain the aggregate functions COUNT_BIG() or SUM(). [...]

Comment: you're correct - I realized that a little while ago but forgot to update this. Thanks for that.  I ended up just re-querying the DB every few seconds....